# apacite error - The style file: apacite.bst Database file #1: ... is a string literal, not a function

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am trying to use the `apacite` package for referencing however I am having some problems getting it to work.

I am using Ubuntu and the Tex Live distribution so I installed the `texlive-bibtex-extra` Ubuntu package which contains `apacite`.

I am using a bibtex file that works fine with `natbib` but for some reason does not work here. `Jung2009` is one of my references.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

example example example \cite{Jung2009}. 

\bibliographystyle{apacite}%{unsrt}
\bibliography{library}

\end{document}
```

I initially had problems with citing in captions but solved that by placing `\protect` in front of the `\cite` commands.

However I still get the following error when I try to compile

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: apa_practice.aux
The style file: apacite.bst
Database file #1: library.bib
apacite.bst [2013/07/04 v6.02 APA bibliography style]
"" is a string literal, not a function, for entry Jung2009 while executing---line 5144 of file apacite.bst
(There was 1 error message)
```

EDIT: My .bib file is automatically generated from my reference manager Mendeley. Here is the input for `Jung2009`.

```
@article{Jung2009,
abstract = {...},
author = {Jung, Christian and M\"{u}ller, Andreas E},
doi = {10.1016/j.tplants.2009.07.005},
file = {:home/geff/Documents/Mendeley Files/Jung and Muller.pdf:pdf},
issn = {1878-4372},
journal = {Trends Plant Sci.},
keywords = {...},
month = oct,
number = {10},
pages = {563--73},
pmid = {19716745},
title = {{Flowering time control and applications in plant breeding.}},
url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19716745},
volume = {14},
year = {2009}
}
```

EDIT2: by running apacite.ins in the folder with my .tex file I can get apacite to run and the above example works great. However now every citation in my real document causes an !Undefined Control Sequence Error. Even when I delete all other related files in the folder. Could it be other packages interfering? 
Here is my preamble, based off a template:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{apacite}


\usepackage[
breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=blue,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=20mm,right=20mm,
bindingoffset=10mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}

\OnehalfSpacing
%\linespread{1.3}

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{brotherton}
%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}


%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
\pagestyle{plain}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}


\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} 
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `kpsewhich apacite.bst` returns `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/apacite/apacite.bst`  I am unfamiliar with `\listfiles`. How do I recognise it in the log as what I think it is is very long

Comment: I have `2013/07/21 v6.03 APA bibliography style` in my `.blg` file: I see after a bit of a tweak of the question formatting that you have `v6.02`. Before pursuing anything else, I'd be tempted to try grabbing the latest version from CTAN and using that (in the same folder as the `.tex` file). BTW, is that the exact text of your `.bib` entry: I'm suspicious of the `{...}` parts.

Comment: I think this might be something quite basic or fundamental as now I try it with natbib I get a lot of !Undefined Control Sequence Errors

Comment: Did you delete the `.bbl` file before trying that? `apacite` includes various special bits and pieces in the auxiliary files: usually for testing it's best to remove all of these when making changes.

Comment: Ah, I did not know about the .bbl file. So I can still get a document using natbib. Also its not the exact text of my .bib text I edited out the long abstract and keywords sections.

Comment: I tried placing the v6.03 files in the folder with my .tex file but there was no change. It still seems like it is trying to use v6.02

Comment: @G_T - Did you run the full update cycle -- latex, bibtex, and latex twice more -- after updating the .sty and .bst files?

Comment: @Mico Yes I am using the Texmaker editor and it is set to do Pdflatex -> bibtex -> Pdflatex -> Pdflatex

Comment: @G_T - Were you able to ascertain from the .log file whether you're using the 6.02 or the 6.03 files?

Comment: @Mico - yes, even when I copied the v6.03 into the folder with my .tex file the log still reads english.apc 2013/07/04 v6.02 apacite language file

Comment: What about copying v6.03 in your local TeXMF instead?

Comment: Playing around I found I have to run the apacite.ins. Then apacite works. However now every citation in my document causes a !Undefined Control Sequence Error. Even when I delete all other related files in the folder.

Comment: Are there any news here?