# \protect with \cite inside \caption

Tags: captions, citing

I've read several posts and other webpages now on using `\protect` in front of `\cite` inside `\caption`. They all advise using `\protect` in this situation, and many go as far as to say that you *must* use it.

Now, I've been able to use `\cite` inside `\caption` without `\protect` and still get no errors. For example, the following works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
Hello
\caption{I cite this \cite[p. 41]{lang:cyc}.}
\end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{lang:cyc}
S.~Lang.
\newblock {\em Cyclotomic fields {I} and {II}}, volume 121 of {\em Graduate Texts in Mathematics}.
\newblock Springer-Verlag, New York, second edition, 1990.
\newblock With an appendix by Karl Rubin.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I'm interested to know, therefore, whether `\protect` is strictly necessary in this context. Could it be that it's sometimes not necessary (as in the above), but that it's best to use it anyway because you never know when some intricate circumstance might make it necessary?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, unless some package redefines `\cite` in a “fragile” way. By default, `\cite` is a robust command.

Comment: I've found [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165394/), which is an example of a package redefining `\cite` in a fragile way (`apacite.sty`).

Comment: I use `\cite` without problems in captions, also `\ref` works fine. The only occasion I had to use `\protect` inside a caption, was when I created a sub-figure and used `\subref` within the main caption. [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62636/referencing-subfigures-in-main-caption-with-subfloat-and-subref]

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be necessary, because the kernel `\cite` command is robust. Also the main packages for managing bibliographies, such as `natbib` and `biblatex` have care to redefine `\cite` in a robust fashion.

Some packages, unfortunately don't, for example `apacite` (but `natbib` emulates it pretty well). In such a case, `\protect` would become necessary.

Adding `\protect` when not strictly necessary shouldn't be a problem, though.