# Giving book reference to figures

Tags: cross-referencing, back-referencing

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{1.png}
\caption{Motion of Body \textit{H}}
\label{fig:two}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How do I cite reference of a book for the above figure?

Comment: Do you want to add a citation to a book in the figure caption?  If so, use `\caption{text \cite{} text}`.

Comment: @James -- since `\caption` is a "movable" element (saved for use in list of figures, etc.), `\cite` should be "protected": `\protect\cite{...}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton With the new kernel (2015), there's no need to protect `\cite` since it was defined using `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks for that tip.  I found another question discussing `\protect` and `\cite` that might interest the OP.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174275/protect-with-cite-inside-caption

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- thanks,  i think it likely that the op may not yet be using tex live 2015, but this is good to know for the future.  actually, this "upgrade" was made some time ago, so it's probably okay.  (but if it fails, `\protect` is still available.)

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for your Inputs. I want to add another caption with reference to a book @James @ barbarabeeton

Comment: @Bruce -- do you mean you want two captions for the same figure, or is this a caption to a different figure?  (two captions for the same figure isn't going to work, but you can make another paragraph within the one caption, using `\endgraf` if the usual blank line doesn't work.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- I want to give book reference to my sketch. I am looking for a best possible way to do it. For example, when a diagram from a book is taken the author reference along with the year of publication is shown below it. I want something similar for my figure. Is it possible in Latex?

Comment: @Bruce -- this may be better handled as a separate question.  it sounds like the form of reference you want is what is produced by an author-year style.  that's not a simple `\cite`.  do enter a new question, referencing this one, and in it, add the following information to what's in your example here: the bibliography style you're using, any related packages (i'm thinking `natbib`), and an appropriate bib entry. you might first look at this: [Natbib: Author-year in the text but numbered bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228914/579).

Comment: [How do correct citing of figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236605)

Comment: @Johannes_B : I confirmed it with my supervisor. Seems like numeric would be enough. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to cite the reference in the caption of your figure, just modify the `\caption` line for something like

```
\caption{Motion of Body \textit{H}, from \cite{thebook}}
```

Where `thebook` is the label you assigned to it in the bibliography section. For example:

```
\begin{thebibliography}
    \bibitem{thebook} Authors, Title, Editorial, Place, Year.
\end{thebibliography}
```